# soapcpp2 can't generate soapClient.c file

Tags: gsoap

I am trying to build a tr069 client using gsoap. I followed the instructions in the document but I could not get soapClient.c.

Here is the steps:

1. wsdl2h -c -o tr069.h cwmp-1-1.xsd  --> this generate tr069.h
2. soapcpp2 -c tr069.h --> this only generates the following file:

ns1.nsmap, soapC.c soapH.h soapStub.h

According to the examples online and in the document, I am suppose to get file like soapClient.c

Does anyone knows why? I am using gsoap 2.8

Thanks.

Comment: A few questions: Can you post a link to the instructions you are following?  Exactly which version of gsoap are you using, soapcpp2 -v should tell you?  What OS are you running this on?

Comment: I was following the steps someone posts on yahoo gsoap group. I can post it later. I am using gsoap release 2.8.5. I am running this on 64 bit ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The cwmp-1-1.xsd is only an XSD file. You do not have a WSDL defining the operations that normally are stored in soapClient.c. However, you can still use the XML root element serializers (see bottom part of tr069.h for instructions) over sockets etc.